# Print unknown file format to screen

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I got a test file from a robot, I have to program by a C++ program I'm developing. So I wanted to use this file to see how the robot saves the coordinates of points. My program is currently able to calculate coordinates, now I have to generate the robot code.

Therefore I wanted to have a look at the file. But it seems that the file is writen in a binary mode. So my first idea was: Open the file in binary mode and print the content to the screen. So this is the code I'm using:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>     // std::cout
  #include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
  #include <Windows.h>

  int main () {
     std::ifstream is ("Test.PRG", std::ifstream::binary);
     if (is) {
          // get length of file:
          is.seekg (0, is.end);
          int length = is.tellg();
          is.seekg (0, is.beg);

          char * buffer = new char [length];

          std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
          // read data as a block:
          is.read (buffer,length);

          if (is)
              std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
          else
              std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";
          is.close();

          // ...buffer contains the entire file...

          for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
          {
            std::cout << (double) buffer[i] << std::endl;
          }

          delete[] buffer;
          }

         Sleep(10000);
         return 0;
   }
```

But with this code I just can't see what is writen in the file. I also tried different conversations than (double). I used char, int and float. Now I just don't know, what i could do more. Is there a possible methode to read this file and convert it to ASCII? I'm also adding the link for the file here, so you can have a look at it.
[Download link for file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xezx4p7c3xurcin/Test.PRG?dl=0)

Comment: Use a text editor that can view binary files, such as Ultra Edit.

Comment: A binary file contains *bytes* or *octets*.  The values are in the range 0 .. 255.  The printable ASCII character set is much smaller.  So there are many *unprintable* values (if you choose to view as characters).  You will need to read the values as `uint8_t` and print them out as integers.  Usually is is done in hexadecimal.

Comment: In *nix systems and Cygwin (for Windows), there is a utility, `od` (octal dump), that can print the contents of a file in octal and decimal.  Research it.  You may even be able to get the source code for it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: So I should change `char * buffer = new char [length];` to `uint8_t * buffer = new uint8_t [length];`?

Comment: No, you should use `std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(1024 * 1024)`.  Also, I don't recommend reading in the entire file into memory.  Read in a block, and display the block.  You may have to pause the display after N records are displayed; thus reading in blocks is valid.

Comment: I just downloaded Ultra Edit. When I open the file I just see the same symbols like in Notepad++.

Comment: Ultra Edit can view files in hex.  Go to Edit | Hex Functions | Hex Edit, or press Ctrl-H.

Comment: I usually use HexFiend for that kind of thing. Here's a nice comparison chart showing various hex editors and their capabilities and cost: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Comment: So I used now UltaEdit and webhex.net and i always get the same result. It's always unreadable for me. Could someone maybe have a look on my file and check it? I would be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture of the beginning of your file that I took with HexFiend:
[image]

Comment: I got the same by UltraEdit. But is this everything saved in this file? There should be more informations in this file like coordinates.

Comment: I'm sure there are coordinates further down in the file. I only printed the beginning. But you're probably going to need a file format specification for PRG files before you can pluck coordinates out of a binary file like this one.

Comment: I looked in the whole file and the the only thing I saw was `WRKCoo` and a number. But I know this is a move command for the robot. The problem is I won't get the specification for PRG form the company providing this robot. So the only possible way to programm the robot is to understand this file

Comment: My next suggestion is to get a sample copy of the `kuka|prc` program and generate a few sample files, then look into them with a hex dump facility. I assume that `kuka|prc` is the program for PRC files; I haven't actually tried this out myself. here's a link for a trial version of the program: http://www.robotsinarchitecture.org/kuka-prc